# limit point compactness and compactness in topological (metric) space

Tags: general-topology

In topological space, when the space is T1 and Lindelöf, then limit point compactness implies compactness. In metric space, however, we may not possess the property of Lindelöf, but why limit point compactness still implies compactness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\langle X,d\rangle$ be a metric space that is limit-point compact. Then $X$ does not contain an infinite closed discrete subset, so for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is a finite $F_n\subseteq X$ such that $\bigcup_{x\in F_n}B\left(x,\frac1n\right)=X$. (In other words, $X$ is [totally bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space).) Let

$$\mathscr{B}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}\left\{B\left(x,\frac1n\right):x\in F_n\right\}\;;$$

$\mathscr{B}$ is a countable family of open sets in $X$, and I claim that $\mathscr{B}$ is a base for the topology of $X$.

To see this, let $U$ be any non-empty open set in $X$, and let $x\in U$; there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq U$. Choose $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\frac1n<\frac12\epsilon$, i.e., $n>\frac2{\epsilon}$. There is a $y\in F_n$ such that $x\in B\left(y,\frac1n\right)$, and it’s easy to check that $B\left(y,\frac1n\right)\subseteq B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq U$. (HINT: Use the triangle inequality.) Clearly $B\left(y,\frac1n\right)\in\mathscr{B}$, so we’ve shown that for each $x\in U$ there is a $B_x\in\mathscr{B}$ such that $x\in B_x\subseteq U$. Thus, $U=\bigcup_{x\in U}B_x$ is a union of members of $\mathscr{B}$, and since $U$ was arbitrary, $\mathscr{B}$ is indeed a base for the topology.

This shows that $X$ is second countable, from which it follows immediately that $X$ is Lindelöf and hence compact.

Comment: I see. So actually in metric space, limit point compactness implies second countability, while in general topological space, it doesn't have such good thing.

Comment: @89085731: That’s right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Lindelöf implies compact in metric spaces? Or maybe limit-point+Lindelöf implies it?

Comment: @JonSK: The latter. In a metric space (indeed, in a $T_1$ space) limit-point compactness is equivalent to countable compactness, which of course yields compactness in the presence of the Lindelöf property.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see, thank you.

Comment: @JonSK: You’re welcome.